# How do I get better indication that my git configuration is wrong?

Tags: magit

I ran magit-status, and was surprised by the absence of changes. It turned out that I'd misconfigured my git textconv settings, so 'git diff' was returning an error. However, I saw no indication of this in magit-status at all (for other git misconfigurations in the past I've seen a git process error buffer). Is there some debug variable I need to turn on?

This is with magit 20180630.1235 from melpa.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Magit (IOW, better report it there than ask here).

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a good idea

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some debug variable I need to turn on?

Yes, setting `magit-git-debug`:

```
magit-git-debug is a variable defined in ‘magit-git.el’.
Its value is nil

Documentation:
Whether to enable additional reporting of git errors.

Magit basically calls git for one of these two reasons: for
side-effects or to do something with its standard output.

When git is run for side-effects then its output, including error
messages, go into the process buffer which is shown when using M-x magit-process.

When git’s output is consumed in some way, then it would be too
expensive to also insert it into this buffer, but when this
option is non-nil and git returns with a non-zero exit status,
then at least its standard error is inserted into this buffer.

This is only intended for debugging purposes.  Do not enable this
permanently, that would negatively affect performance.
```

Comment: "unable to read files to diff", which is not too helpful :-)